# Using promises when response callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to figure out how to use promises in a test I'm writing. I'm using plain ol' native promises in the browser. No libraries (yet)

The test requires communicating asynchronously with a server, where I get the server response via a callback

I have a server object where I register the callback like so:

```
server.onresponse = function(data){
  //do stuff with data
}
```

The test requires sending a series of commands to the server that change based on the servers response. I send the commands to the server like so

```
server.sendCommand({data:"do something"})
```

Based on the command, the server would raise the onresponse callback. I would need to read the data that the server sent to decide what the next command should be.

The interaction should be something like

- send command 1 and wait
- process data from onresponse callback
- send command 2 and wait
- process data from onresponse callback

I would like to use promises to make this interaction read a bit clearer. Like something like a series of `.then()`s .

I realize promises cannot be reused so it's not like I can reset the same promise every time the onresponse callback happens.

Is there a way to do this via promises? I started reading out generators as well. Would those help too?

Thanks

Comment: What about using [`Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)?

Comment: how would events help?

Comment: Yes, this API isn't useful for your task. Why doesn't `sendCommand` return a promise for the response, instead of firing the global `onresponse` callback?

Comment: yup, i had to see it( see accepted answer below), but that makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this:

```
function sendCommand(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
         server.onresponse = resolve;
         server.sendCommand(data);
    });
}
```

and use it like this:

```
sendCommand({data:"do something"})
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return sendCommand({data:"do something else "})
})
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper function to do just what you described.  Pass in the command, and it returns a `Promise` that resolves with the response from the server.  If there is some error handling callback, you should use it as well. For example, let's call it `server.onerror`.  You should replace this with whatever the proper handler is.

```
function sendCommand(cmd) {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server.onresponse = resolve;
    server.onerror = reject;
  });
  server.sendCommand(cmd);
  return promise;
}
```

You would use it just like you described, a promise chain.  Of course, you probably want to do something with the response rather than just fire the next command.  And always remember to handle any errors at the end with `catch`!

```
sendCommand({data: "do thing 1"})
  .then((response) => sendCommand({data: "do thing 2"}))
  .then((response) => sendCommand({data: "do thing 3"}))
  .then((response) => console.log("All done!"))
  .catch((error) => console.log("Oops!"));
```